# C# Filestream not blocking until write/read operation complete

Tags: c#, filestream

I'm trying to write a class that will copy a file from one location to another and report progress. The problem that I'm having is that when the application is run, the progress will shoot from 0 to 100% instantly, but the file is still copying in the background.

```
    public void Copy(string sourceFile, string destinationFile)
    {
        _stopWatch.Start();

        _sourceStream = new FileStream(srcName, FileMode.Open);
        _destinationStream = new FileStream(destName, FileMode.CreateNew);

        read();
        //On a 500mb file, execution will reach here in about a second.
    }

    private void read()
    {
        int i = _sourceStream.Read(_buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        _completedBytes += i;

        if (i != 0)
        {
            _destinationStream.Write(_buffer, 0, i);

            TriggerProgressUpdate();

            read();
        }
    }

    private void TriggerProgressUpdate()
    {
        if (OnCopyProgress != null)
        {
            CopyProgressEventArgs arg = new CopyProgressEventArgs();
            arg.CompleteBytes = _completedBytes;

            if (_totalBytes == 0)
                _totalBytes = new FileInfo(srcName).Length;

            arg.TotalBytes = _totalBytes;

            OnCopyProgress(this, arg);
        }
    }
```

What seems to be happening is that FileStream is merely queuing the operations in the OS, instead of blocking until the read or write is complete.

Is there any way to disable this functionality without causing a huge performance loss?

PS. I am using test source and destination variables, thats why they dont match the arguments.

Thanks
Craig

Comment: As a matter of interest, is there a reason you're forcing your app to copy one file to another byte by byte rather than calling File.Copy()?

Comment: @bitcrazed: Probably to get a progress indicator.

Comment: If so, that's a hell of a perf hit to take just to show the user a moving progress indicator. Why not just show a spinning ball or similar while the file is copying?

Comment: It is to report progress. and get control over the copy operation, pausing, speed limit etc. Another factor is that there could be a few hundred fairly large files being copied, it would be nice for the user to have some idea how far along each file is. I have ran perf tests on the code above and it did not seem too much slower. I will keep an eye on it though, if performance becomes too slow I will have to do something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigating I found that using "FileOptions.WriteThrough" in a FileStream's constructor will disable write caching. This causes my progress to report correctly. It does however take a performance hit, the copy takes 13 seconds in windows and 20 second in my application. I'm going to try and optimize the code and adjust the buffer size to see if I can  speeds things up a bit.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it can be queuing the *read* operations... after all, you've got a byte array, it will have some data in after the `Read` call - that data had better be correct. It's probably only the *write* operations which are being buffered.

You could try calling `Flush` on the output stream periodically... I don't know quite how far the `Flush` will go in terms of the various levels of caching, but it may well wait until the data has actually been written. EDIT: If you know it's a `FileStream`, you can call `Flush(true)` which will wait until the data has actually been written to disk.

Note that you shouldn't do this too often, or performance will suffer significantly. You'll need to balance the granularity of progress accuracy with the performance penalty for taking more control instead of letting the OS optimize the disk access.

I'm concerned about your use of recursion here - on a very large file you may well blow up with a stack overflow for no good reason. (The CLR can sometimes optimize tail-recursive methods, but not always). I suggest you use a loop instead. That would also be more readable, IMO:

```
public void Copy()
{
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = _sourceStream.Read(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        _destinationStream.Write(_buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        _completedBytes += bytesRead;
        TriggerProgressUpdate();
        if (someAppropriateCondition)
        {
            _destinationStream.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you're disposing of the streams somewhere, by the way. Personally I try to avoid having disposable member variables if at all possible. Is there any reason you can't just use local variables in a `using` statement?

Comment: "Personally I try to avoid having disposable member variables if at all possible." - Will it be advisable if Copy is called several times during the applications' life time? Which approach is better, (1) a member field or a (2) method variable that is disposed off everytime after the operation is done. Will (2) won't put pressure on the heap and on GC?. I'm asking because I've a similar req where in a method generates Unique ids using rngcryptoserviceprovider. I've followed the (1) approach.

Comment: @Vijay: Disposing of an object doesn't do anything to the GC. But in this case, when you've finished copying the object, you're *done* with the stream. If you logically have a single object for a long time, then it makes sense to embed that within another object. But here, each time we call `Copy(source, target)` it will replace the variables. I can't see any use for having member variables here.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the Flush(true) idea. The above class implements IDisposable where the streams are disposed. As for the recursion, this is a totally stripped down test method I created to troubleshoot the "buffering issue" the real method does not look like that :) Thanks for the comments about it though, its something new I learned anyways.